# Strange JPA behaviour: tables cleaned at app boot

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, entitymanager, toplink

Almost all is in the title... Persistence is working fine when app launched, and row are still in DB when the app is closed, but once app is loaded, rows got deleted...

I'm using an already existing database structure, through the mysql5 SGBD.

Seems to be coming from my entity manager declaration. Here are a few lines of my code, (entity manager statement, and persistence.xml)

entityManager statement:

```
entityManager = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(resourceMap.getString("entityManager.persistenceUnit")).createEntityManager();
query = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : entityManager.createQuery(resourceMap.getString("query.query"));
```

persistence.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="AnalysesPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider
    <class>solianceanalysesmanager.Produits
    <properties>
      <property name="toplink.jdbc.user" value="XXX"/>
      <property name="toplink.jdbc.password" value="X"/>
      <property name="toplink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Analyses"/>
      <property name="toplink.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Does someone have an idea of this strange problem cause?
I already got suggested that my entityManager was reinitialising persistence context on its statement...

PS: Since i'm french, it's possible i mis-used or mis-spelled some words. Feel free to ask me to reformulate.

Comment: I don't have any experience in Toplink, but when using Hibernate as JPA provider one can tell Hibernate to recreate the whole database schema everytime it starts. Isn't it something similar here?

Comment: @GrzegorzOledski : Somebody already told me about this kind of possibility, but i don't know if TopLink implements a similar feature. If i find a good FAQ about entityManager statement, i'll be able to clear that point, and maybe solve the problem. Still need the good FAQ, thought...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TopLink Essentials does not recreate your tables by default, but this can be configured in your persistence.xml.

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/DDL

My guess is you are using Glassfish?  I believe Glassfish does this by default in development mode, and there is some Glassfish setting you need to configure to avoid this.  I'm not sure how this is configured in Glassfish though, perhaps someone else does.

Comment: I'm not using Glassfish, since i'm not going for a JEE architecture. It would have the form of a desktop application, all of the code executed on client computer, and linked to a mysql server (as said in first post).

Comment: The builded project is working fine. Netbeans does have this stupid default behavior too... Too bad it wasn't explained anywhere. =)

Answer (score 2):

So, the problem was: Netbeans default behavior is an automatic "drop and create" strategy, despite the persistence.xml settings.

Once you build the project, using the .jar won't reset the databases table.

Comment: thanks for reporting back your discovery. More people should do that!

Answer (score 1):

your persistence.xml miss some properties definition...you have to specify to the entity manager how to behave, it's taking the drop and create parameters as default setting. that's why all rows are deleted when app is loaded.. try to add this line to change jpa behaviour :

```
<property name="toplink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
```

Comment: My persistence.xml doesn't miss this line. I need it to use the default exploitation-mode behaviour, which is fine. But the default developpment-mode behaviour is a "drop-and-create", while the exploitation-mode is a "do-nothing". Just building the project and using the buil solved the problem, as said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001927/strange-jpa-behaviour-tables-cleaned-at-app-boot/5005626#5005626)... By the way, you shouldn't try to grind rep on already answered questions... kthxbye.